# Autodesk Viewing save markups in MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I’m integrating the Autodesk Viewer API and I was following the tutorial at http://learnforge.autodesk.io. I’m currently working on the markups, using the MarkupsCore extension and am able to manipulate the different markup types.

What I’m trying to do is save in a mongoDB database the svg that I get when I do markup.generateData(), then display it whenever I want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a blog about extracting and restoring the markups:
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension

We don't exactly have a tutorial about persisting markups to mongoDB or any other data source but that process is similar to persisting any other JSON data from the browser to your backend. You can however find some pointers in our RCDB example:
https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/

Comment: Thanks a million. Let me try this out !!